bypassing integrityError gotten from unique field in a django model
I want a unique field generated at database level. The way unique=True works is it raises an error if it see's a duplicate value in the database. I don't want that though, I want it to simply generate a new unique number instead of raising an error.
This is the model that gives a user an account number, Any help will be much appreciated
class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    account_number = ShortUUIDField(unique=True,length=10, max_length=25, prefix="217", alphabet="1234567890")



Seems like you are using thrid-party package django-shortuuidfield
According to it's docs it automatically generates TEXT, that looks like short uuid.
Not on database level.
And it's short, so it has low entropy(randomness)
So you should try-except creation of new Account. Maybe even with some recursive function to prevent double-fail scenario (generate till no IntegrityError)
OR use actual Django UUIDField

I don't think Django UUIDField is sufficient for this use case. I need the generated characters to be strictly numbers and they have to be 11 numbers to be specific

Then you need to catch integrity error on account number creation. 11 digits is low "randomness" stuff. Recursive function ,(create until created) will do the trick.

Ooor you could make an integer pk autoincrement field, starting with 10.000.000.000 :)

You can override the save method in your model to catch the integrity error raised in this method and set a new value for your account number.
import random
import string

class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    account_number = CharField(unique=True,length=10, max_length=25)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        saved = False
        while(!saved)
            try:
                super().save(*args, **kwargs)
                saved=True
            except IntegrityError:
                length = 10 # Set this value to fit your needs
                self.account_number = '217' + ''.join(random.choice(string.digits) for _ in range(length))
            


This solution seems to work just fine with a few tweaks to the loop
